# How to use XPath to find nodes in the XML attribute with ref?

Tags: xpath, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to access the attribute/element nodes with ref in the below xsd

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="arcAttrs">
    <xs:attribute ref="xlink:type" use="required" fixed="arc"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="xlink:arcrole"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="xlink:title"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="xlink:show"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="xlink:actuate"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="xlink:from"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="xlink:to">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
 from and to have default behavior when values are missing
</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:attributeGroup>
<xs:group name="arcModel">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="xlink:title" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
<xs:complexType name="arcType">
    <xs:group ref="xlink:arcModel"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="xlink:arcAttrs"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

I try to access it by

```
 <bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='arcType']">
                <bindings node="xs:group/xs:element[@ref='xlink:title']">
                    <property name="arcModelTitle"/>
                </bindings>

        </bindings>
```

but it doesn't work……  what should I do about this?

What I want to do is : generate JAVA package from xsd by xjc. However，there’re some name conflict in the xsd, like the error below:

```
[ERROR] Property "Title" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
line 197 of file:/D:/0Ubiloc/TEST/xlink.xsd
[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
line 183 of file:/D:/0Ubiloc/TEST/xlink.xsd
```

so I want to redefined the name of the attribute or the element. But it failed to get the node(attribute/element) with ref, just like the code I stick out on the floor 1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! 1) Define "doesn't work". What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? 2) What framework are the `<bindings>` from? Is this JAXB? If so, please tag your question with `jaxb` (and `xsd`).

Comment: Thank you for your tips so much!
What I want to do is : generate JAVA package from xsd by xjc .However，there’re some name conflict in the xsd,like the error below:

[ERROR] Property "Title" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 197 of file:/D:/0Ubiloc/TEST/xlink.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 183 of file:/D:/0Ubiloc/TEST/xlink.xsd

so I want to redefined the name of the attribute or the element.But it failed to get the node(attribute/element) with ref,just like the code I stick out on the floor 1.@LarsH

Comment: OK. I don't know the answer, but I've added tags, and your error message, to the question so that others can understand it better.

Comment: @May Did you ever solve this?